# D3js graph is not showing

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, d3.js

I am trying to make graph using data updated from MySQL and representing it using d3js. The files I am using are:

app.js

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var getRouter = require('./src/routes/getRoutes'); 

var port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.use(express.static('./src'));

app.set('views', './src/views');      
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/get', getRouter.getget());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Thickness Graph'
    });
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('running server on port ' + port) 
});
```

src/routes/getRoutes.js

```
    express = require('express'),
    getRouter = express.Router(),        
    mysql = require('mysql');


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    connectionLimit : 1,
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'pass',
    database : 'thickness',
    port: 3307
});

var getget = function(){

    getRouter.route('/')    
    .get(function(req,res){
        connection.query('select * from test1_shivam where Record=(select max(Record) from test1_shivam)', req.params.id, function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.statusCode = 500;
                res.send({
                    result: 'error',
                    err: err.code
                });
            }
            res.send(rows[0]);

        }); 
    });
    return getRouter;
};

module.exports = {
  getget: getget
};
```

src/views/index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<style>
.bar-chart {
  background-color: #C7D9D9;
  }
</style>

<body>

<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var url = 'http://localhost:4000/get'
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {

var dataset = Object.values(data)

var svgWidth = 1500, svgHeight = 400, barPadding = 5;
var barWidth = svgWidth / dataset.length
var svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr("width", svgWidth)
    .attr("height", svgHeight);

var barChart = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
         return svgHeight - d 
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) { 
        return d; 
    })
    .attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        var translate = [barWidth * i, 0]; 
        return "translate("+ translate +")";
    });

var text = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return svgHeight - d - 2;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return barWidth * i;
    })
    .attr("fill", "#A64C38");
  })
</script>
</body>
```

The data in object type I am getting is 
[the data through /get I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTTaI.png)
The other task I have to do is to make real-time graph. The further suggestions for same will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append svg element

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
```

before `d3.select("svg")`

Comment: Thanks a lot Madz. I have to make basic real-time graph from this. Should I use sockets.io or something else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: socket.io is preferred for real time applications